# org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log

Tags: logging, groovy, websphere

I have an application which is deployed on Websphere 8.5, the class loading is configured to "Parent Last".

In the application, we use GroovyScriptEngine to run a groovy script file.

Here is the groovy script:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.2' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

new File('grab.log').delete()
File file = new File('grab.log')
try{
    file << '11111\n\n'

    def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
    def html = http.get( path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'] )
    file << html

    file << '\n\n22222'

}catch(e){
    file << org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)
}
```

JARs are downloaded successfully into folder .groovy/grapes, but the code line `def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')` results in an error:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:395)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:173)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.createClient(HTTPBuilder.java:858)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.getClient(HTTPBuilder.java:842)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:285)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:255)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at abc.run(abc.groovy:54)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:551)
    at com.mh.test.MHGroovyScriptEngine.runScript(MHGroovyScriptEngine.java:218)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter$1$1.call(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:777)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:412)
    ... 25 more
```

I found that Jdk14Logger exists in these 2 places(at least), and they both do implement Log

1. .groovy\grapes\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, this is automatically downloaded by groovy grape
2. IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-logging.jar, this is provided by websphere

I've googled it for several hours and tried solutions I have ever found, but none of them work for me.

Another thing is the same thing works fine on tomcat.

Anyone has any suggestion or explanation about why this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere comes with it's own commons-logging, as you mentioned. I would remove the local one (groovy) from classpath no matter what class loader policy you use.
It happens because your app is loaded first along with all its local resources (PARENT_LAST = LOCAL_FIRST). Since WAS uses commons-logging internally as well, and your - much newer - version is loaded, some internal WAS components don't like it for obvious reasons.

Comment: I remove the local commons-logging, and use GrabExclude(group='commons-logging', module='commons-logging') in groovy to not download it, but still same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the full trace, so that we can see from where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a common occurrence on WebSphere when an application provides its own Commons Logging JAR.  WebSphere's factory-shipped version is modified, and is not compatible with the standard Apache versions.

The common fixes for it are to either:

- Remove the application's version of commons-logging.
- Change the classloader setting to PARENT_LAST

The [JCL FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Logging/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) has more information on issues with WebSphere.